# Why isn't parseInt a method?

Tags: javascript

Why is parseInt a function instead of a method?

Function:

```
var i = parseInt(X);
```

Method:

```
var i = X.parseInt();
```

Comment: Because it would throw an error if X was undefined?

Comment: @jishi: If `X` is `undefined`, you'll always get an error when trying to access a property. Not sure what that would have to do with `parseInt` not being a method of `Number`.

Comment: @amnotiam `parseInt(undefined) === NaN` if `parseint` were a method of `String` or `Number` then `undefined.parseInt()` would throw an exception not return `NaN`

Comment: @OriginalSyn: It would seem to be a given that if `String` had a `parseInt` method, then you'd need to be working with a `String` object to invoke it. Same with `Boolean`, `Array`, etc...

Comment: Yes, parsing integers from strings is the most common use case. But you may not know where the variable `X` is coming from. E.g., `function(X) { var i = X.parseInt(); /* do some code */ }` in such a case you now have to do try/catching instead of an if conditional for `isNaN`

Comment: @OriginalSyn: Yes, and that's why they made it a global function. I'm just saying that it seems fairly obvious that if it's a method of a constructor's prototype, then you'd need to be working with that type to use it.

Comment: When parsing a decimal number from a string, I prefer to use unary plus operator in front the string in braces, +(string), instead parseInt or parseFloat, like in this example:


x = +("1" + "20"); // to x is assigned a number 120, after its conversion from a string "120"

Comment: Not an answer, but I got tired of wrapping long method chains inside the parseInt function. I made the following monkey patch: `String.prototype.parseInt = function() { return parseInt(this) }`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:**

I'm not 100% sure why `parseInt` isn't a method of `String`, except that it can be run on anything. Seems it could be part of `Math` but it isn't really a mathematical operation either.

**End Edit**

`parseInt` is a method of the global object.  In the browser, the global object is `window`.  You could call `window.parseInt()`, but the JS engine lets you shortcut calls to global methods.

That said, there is some cost to it as the engine must scan the scope chain looking for definitions of `parseInt`. Generally, if I am making a single to call to such a method within a scope, I will reference it off the global:

```
var foo = function (someString) {
    var bar;

    // ...

    bar = window.parseInt(someString, 10);

    // ...
};
```

If my code needs to make more than one call to the method within a scope, however, I localize it and use the reference:

```
var foo = function (someString, someOtherString) {
    var parseInt = window.parseInt,
      bar,
      baz;

    // ...

    bar = parseInt(someString, 10);
    baz = parseInt(someOtherString, 10);

    // ...
};
```

Comment: I think he's probably asking why it isn't a method of `Number`.

Comment: Yes, perhaps he is--though I think it's closer to "why isn't `parseInt` a method of `String`?".

Comment: @amnotiam - that's what I also figured, but parseInt() doesn't have to (and probably shouldn't (well, at least it's not necessary to run it on numbers)) be run on numbers but on everything _but_ numbers (I guess that's why it isn't a method of `Number`).

Comment: @powerbuoy: Very good point. It's useful still on floats, but clearly it would need to be elsewhere too.

Comment: That's interesting that you would localize the reference.  Could you default the radix to 10 as well?

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn not without aliasing the function to something which then calls `parseInt` with a hard coded radix.